# Filter list of scheduled tasks and show only "Next Run Time"

Tags: cmd, windows-task-scheduler

schtasks cmd which i'm running: `schtasks /query /fo LIST /tn PDFGeneration`

Result:

```
Folder: \
HostName:      MIA-MATERNITY
TaskName:      \PDFGeneration
Next Run Time: 06/01/2015 02:35:00
Status:        Ready
Logon Mode:    Interactive only
```

I want to be able to show only:

```
Next Run Time: 06/01/2015 02:35:00
```

Is it possible to do this?

**Answer by DavidPostill** - [Check the full answer by him](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27324462/3296661)

> From a command line:
>
> ```
> for /f "usebackq tokens=5" %a in (`schtasks /query /fo LIST /tn PDFGeneration ^| findstr /c:"Next Run Time"`) do echo %a
> From a batch file:
> ```
>
> Note that in a batch file %a must be replaced by %%a.
>
> ```
> for /f "usebackq tokens=5" %%a in (`schtasks /query /fo LIST /tn PDFGeneration ^| findstr /c:"Next Run Time"`) do echo %%a
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference [FINDSTR - Search for strings in files](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

> **Syntax**
>
> `FINDSTR [options] [/F:file] [/C:string] [/G:file] [/D:DirList]
>   [/A:color] [/OFF[LINE]] [string(s)] [pathname(s)]`
>
> `FINDSTR [options] [/F:file] [/R] [/G:file] [/D:DirList] [/A:color]
>   [/OFF[LINE]] [string(s)] [pathname(s)]`
>
> **Key**
>
> `string`      Text to search for.    `pathname(s)` The file(s) to
>   search.
>     `/C:string`   **Use string as a literal search string**.
>   `/R`          Use string as a regular expression.
>   `/G:file`     Get
>   search string from a file (/ stands for console).
>   `/F:file`     Get
>   a list of pathname(s) from a file (/ stands for console).
>   `/A:color`    Display filenames in colour (2 hex digits)
>   `/d:dirlist`  Search a comma-delimited list of directories.

The following command will find all lines containing the exact string `Next Run Time`

```
schtasks /query /fo LIST /tn PDFGeneration | findstr /c:"Next Run Time"
```

**How do I extract just the time from the output?**

```
Next Run Time: 06/01/2015 02:35:00
```

This can be done using [FOR /F - Loop command: against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and extracting the 5th token (the for token delimiter is a <kbd>space</kbd> character by default).

From a command line:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=5" %a in (`schtasks /query /fo LIST /tn PDFGeneration ^| findstr /c:"Next Run Time"`) do echo %a
```

From a batch file:

Note that in a batch file `%a` must be replaced by `%%a`.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=5" %%a in (`schtasks /query /fo LIST /tn PDFGeneration ^| findstr /c:"Next Run Time"`) do echo %%a
```

Comment: thank you, this work like a charm. So with the findstr command i'll be able to find just the "02:35:00"?

Comment: You want just the time instead of the whole line?

Comment: that would be great, if you could provide me with some help in doing that?

Comment: I've looked at splitting the string, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thank you David. That's the method i found, i was using %a instead of %%a. Thank you for making it easy to understand!

Comment: @DavidPostill you should spend `findstr` an additional `/c:`. Without, it finds every line that contain `Next` or `Run` or `Time` (although in this special case it doesn't matter)

Comment: @Stephan Oops. I missed it out of the detailed commands (it was in the first command). Thanks. Answer fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
schtasks /query /fo LIST /tn PDFGeneration | findstr Next
```

produces the desired output.

Comment: Please improve the quality of this post. Thanks.

Comment: Why have you copied this from my (almost 2 year old) answer?

Comment: If you read the comments from my (accepted) answer you will see the OP only wants the time. So the answer  to "is this output the desired?" is no.

Comment: Hi David! You are right. I did not read down the threads and thought the first line was desired. No copying intended, sorry. ^_^